# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed while parsing XML string with browser's built in parser

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I am trying to parse a XML string with browser's built in parser using JavaScript. My XML string looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
            xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
            xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema XMLSchema.xsd'
            elementFormDefault='qualified'
            version='1.0'>
<xsd:element name='probeMetadata' type='OASIS.System.Processor.LinuxProcessorProbe' />
<xsd:complexType name='OASIS.System.Processor.LinuxProcessorProbe'>
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base='OASIS.System.Processor.ProcessorProbe'>
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name='nice_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />
    <xsd:element name='iowait_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />
    <xsd:element name='irq_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />
    <xsd:element name='soft_irq_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name='OASIS.System.Processor.ProcessorProbe'>
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name='idle_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />
    <xsd:element name='system_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />
    <xsd:element name='user_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I wrote a simple JavaScript code just to check whether parser is parsing my XML properly and converting it into valid XML DOM. JavaScript code looks like this:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");

x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;

document.getElementById("Text1").value = x[3].nodeName;
```

Here "text" is above XML. This code means nothing. I just wanted to test someting simple at first. I tested the XML at w3school.com for validity and it didnt give me error so i suppose there is no error in XML.

Comment: What browser are you using? How are you loading the XML? What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Why not use the [W3C validation service](http://validator.w3.org/)? Makes sense to use the service that is supported by the organisation that wrote the standard.

Comment: I am using Chrome 19. parseFromString loads the XML for you. I got following message:"XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://localhost:49669/XSD_Parsing.aspx Line Number 1, Column 96:"

Comment: @RobG : I tested my XML using link provided by you in last comment. XML passed that validation test.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik Can you add the XML input you're using to your question?

Comment: Yes I did. Its at the start of question.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik How about the relevant code in XSD_Parsing.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. I am using Chrome 20.0.1132.21 beta-m.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function test(){
            var text = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\r\n"
            + "<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'\r\n"
            + "            xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'\r\n"
            + "            xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema XMLSchema.xsd'\r\n"
            + "            elementFormDefault='qualified'\r\n"
            + "            version='1.0'>\r\n"
            + "<xsd:element name='probeMetadata' type='OASIS.System.Processor.LinuxProcessorProbe' />\r\n"
            + "<xsd:complexType name='OASIS.System.Processor.LinuxProcessorProbe'>\r\n"
            + "<xsd:complexContent>\r\n"
            + "<xsd:extension base='OASIS.System.Processor.ProcessorProbe'>\r\n"
            + "<xsd:sequence>\r\n"
            + "    <xsd:element name='nice_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />\r\n"
            + "    <xsd:element name='iowait_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />\r\n"
            + "    <xsd:element name='irq_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />\r\n"
            + "    <xsd:element name='soft_irq_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />\r\n"
            + "</xsd:sequence>\r\n"
            + "</xsd:extension>\r\n"
            + "</xsd:complexContent>\r\n"
            + "</xsd:complexType>\r\n"
            + "<xsd:complexType name='OASIS.System.Processor.ProcessorProbe'>\r\n"
            + "<xsd:sequence>\r\n"
            + "    <xsd:element name='idle_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />\r\n"
            + "    <xsd:element name='system_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />\r\n"
            + "    <xsd:element name='user_time' type='xsd:unsignedLong'  />\r\n"
            + "</xsd:sequence>\r\n" + "</xsd:complexType>\r\n"
            + "</xsd:schema>"
            parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
            x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
            document.getElementById("Text1").value = x[3].nodeName;         

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="click" onClick="test()"/>
    <input type="text" name="Text1" id="Text1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wasn't formatting the XML properly. I forgot about whole \r\n thing.Can you tell me why \r\n are so important. Thanks.